# Deploy ExpressTS to vercel

Tags: typescript, express, backend, vercel

I have created an express typescript project on GitHub and trying to deploy to vercel. Below is the folder structure, and dist is where app.js will be in and src is where app.ts is in.

- dist
- dto
- middlewares
- models
- src
- .gitignore
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- README.md
- tsconfig.json
- vercel.json

And this is my vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./app.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the setting on vercel when deploy

- build command: tsc -p .
- output directory: dist
- other settings are just default

Github url for this project is https://github.com/FrankJi1019/today-diary-backend, please feel free to take a look if my description is not clear enough

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You should delete the output folder in the .gitignore file, in my case is dist. Then build Project

And update your vercel.json like this

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./dist/app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/dist/app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this help